# How Automatic Refresh of Power BI Dashboard without on-premises Data Gateway

Tags: azure, powerbi, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-datagateway

I have some concerns regarding my Power BI dashboard. Although I have scheduled a refresh for it, I worry that if my computer is switched off during that time, the refresh won't take place, leaving my dashboard out-of-date.

Hence, I'm curious to know if there is an alternative way to automatically refresh the dashboard without relying on my computer to be turned on.

Answer (score 2):

- If you don't depend on data sources on your local computer, the refresh will work just fine.
- If you depend on file data sources on your local computer, move them to SharePoint and import them from there.

Comment: Yep.  And OneDrive will synchronize local folders to either OneDrive online or SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Followup on @peter's answer:

- when your datasource is located in sharepoint, configure your refresh as OAuth2 with privacy organizational.
- considering data might be birthed on your computer, you could use for example PowerAutomate to periodically check if you personal data gateway is online and extract datasources from your computer when online, thus ensuring the most up-to-date dashboard as possible.